# Strings and StringBuffer

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I have a method that I want to return some path of a string 
example if I input : xxdrrryy - it should return rrr, I can only return a string of length 3, so I am trying this , but I'm stalked . it must be the occurrence of a letter three times consecutively

```
public String countTriple(String str) {
    int count = 1;
    char currChar = str.charAt(0);
    for(int i=1; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(currChar == str.charAt(i)) {
            count++;
            if(count == 3) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
                for(int j=0; j<3;j++) {
                    sb.append(currChar);
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }
        else {
            count = 1;
        }
        currChar = str.charAt(i);
    }
    return null; //no triple found
}
```

Comment: You should give the search in here a try

Comment: Try my answer. It's working. Originally there was a small bug, but its fine now.

Comment: yes I will now @Shn_Android_Dev

Comment: what if there are more then one match for example `aaabcccdeee` did you want just `aaa` or all `aaa, ccc, eee` ?

Comment: yes did not think of this situation , I was checking for one occurrence but that's a nice suggestion @YCF_L

Comment: so you want more than one in this case, right?

Comment: what characters type in your input?

Comment: bybexxxvvyyyy should output xxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason not to, I suggest using a regex.

Something like this should suffice

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1\\1");
Matcher m = p.matcher("abbccc");
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Just import `java.util.regex.*`

Comment: yes that works thanks @Frank Underwood ,  can I get an up vote to remove a ban ?

Comment: @valik If it works, I suggest accepting and upvoting it

Answer (score 2):

Please update your description it is very difficult to understand what you are trying to say.
But as far as I am understanding you want to find out the count of a particular character in a string.
Say you input "aabbbcccc" then it should return c has 4 characters or something like that.

If that is the case, then simple traverse over each character in that string and add them inside the HashTable and increase the count everytime the character is found, and return the value you require.

I hope this might help you.

Comment: if u input aabbbcccc it should return bbb because the rule is cccc has four occurrence and it should be maximum of three occurrence and not less @Ankit Kumar Singh

Comment: That's an easy task. You just need to add a check for that.

Comment: yes I am trying that right now @Ankit Kumar Singh  can I get an up vote to remove a ban ?

Comment: for some reason it gives no return value @Ankit Kumar Singh

Answer (score 2):

This code works. Try this:

```
public static String countTriple(String str) {

    int count = 1;
    char currChar = str.charAt(0);
    for(int i=1; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(currChar == str.charAt(i)) {
            count++;
            if(count == 3) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
                for(int j=0; j<3;j++) {
                    sb.append(currChar);
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }
        else {
            count = 1;
        }
        currChar = str.charAt(i);
    }
    return null; //no triple found
}
```